# Error: strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimiter

Tags: php, strpos

I got this littel problem here with this code

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">

    1<input type="text" name="A" <br>
    2<input type="text" name="B" <br>
    3<input type="text" name="C" <br>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>

</form>
```

and PHP

```
<?php

$a = $_POST['A'];  $b = $_POST['B'];  $c = $_POST['C'];
if(!isset($a , $b) || trim($a , $b ) == '' )
{
    echo "empty" ;
}
$szukaj = strpos($a,$b );

if ($szukaj === false ) {
    echo 'hehe ';
} else {
    echo 'hihi ';
}
?>
```

Icant deal with this error... Can somebody give some tip ,or advice...  what i do wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568016/how-do-i-resolve-a-strpos-empty-delimiter-error

Comment: Error is when fields are empty this ...have to do whit  $needle($b) when is empty . But i dont know how to fiugre it..

Comment: Note that `trim($a , $b )` will treat `$b` as the list of characters to be trimmed from `$a`.... I think you meant to use `|| trim($a) == '' || trim($b ) == ''`

Comment: Both are empty .. When i fill them its okey . But if they are empty i want msg to fill them not error

Comment: have you tried to see the value of `$a` and `$b`?

Comment: "hoijui " - When i fill fields example ( $a = okey , $b = k  it shows = 1 ) but if i leave empty fields and press submit error is showing  . I try arguments fields $a and $b when empty but error still show .. And i asking if there  a way to solve this error to not show when fields are empty.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you should do like this:

```
<?php
$a = $_POST['A'];  $b = $_POST['B'];  $c = $_POST['C'];
if(!empty($a) || empty($b) || trim($a) == '' || trim($b) == '') {
    echo "empty" ;
} else {
    $szukaj = strpos($a, $b);
    if ($szukaj === false ) {
        echo 'hehe ';
    } else {
        echo 'hihi ';
    }
}
?>
```

Your checking for empty were a bit off, and you have to use an else on the empty conditions to only run the strpos if they aren't empty.
I've also placed the other if in the else to be sure the $szukaj variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

your html is wrong, I've tidied it up a bit for you

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    1<input type="text" name="A" /><br />
    2<input type="text" name="B" /><br />
    3<input type="text" name="C" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br />
</form>
```

Comment: I guess all this is just written fast and for a test to show the error he gets, since everything seems too "testing" to be used in real code, imagine variables called a, b, c and echo 'hehe' and echo 'hihi'.